# How to formally and politely ask for details of an yet-to-be-advised interview

Tags: word-choice, sentence-choice

I would like to email a Consulate-General in regards to a job application I made sometime ago. I have received an acceptance letter stating they will get back to me with the details regarding the interview.
I haven't heard anything yet and would like to email them.

I have written the following letter, but I feel it still sounds very colloquial and may hinder my interview.

The email I would like to write is:

> Dear Sir/Madame,
>
> I have received a letter dated on the XXth of [name of month] 2019 from the Embassy of XXXXX for an interview in the Consulate General of XXXXX in late [name of month] 2020 stating that I will be contacted with the details of my interview.
>
> ***However, I have not been contacted yet and would kindly request the details for the interview***.
>
> Kindest Regards,
>
> XXXXX XXXXX

The **bold** and *italicised* sentence, I feel, is far too informal and perhaps a little colloquial.

**Question:**

What would be an appropriate substitution for this sentence, conveying the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fine to me, and one thing to note is that these things are always difficult to write, as there is generally a concern about being bothersome (which could go against you).

I would probably write something like:

> I have yet to be contacted and am wondering if you are able to provide these details.

The way you write it will also often depend on how long away the event is, as if it's only a few days, you are then able to express more concern without seeming pushy, etc.

I would also consider that if there is still plenty of time, it may be best to delay writing the letter, and to see if anything comes through before you really need to contact them.

Comment: is it `I *am* yet to be....` or `I *have* yet to be....`, also `..and am wondering` or do I omit the `am` to yield `and wondering if...`

Comment: It is “have”. I’m struggling to think of an explanation, but consider: If you had been contacted, you would say “I have been contacted”, and not, “I am contacted”, as it immediately becomes past tense, and not a statement about what one is. This would also mean you need to keep it as “am wondering”. Sorry I couldn’t be more scholarly with this one! :)